# Concatenate SQL Results by Year (Year, Make, Model)

Tags: mysql, sql, concatenation

I have a fairly simple query which I'm using to fetch vehicle attributes such as year, make, and model. The data currently looks similar to this...:

```
+------+------+-----------+-------+----------+------------------------------------------+
| SKU  | Year |   Make    | Model | Submodel |                  Notes                   |
+------+------+-----------+-------+----------+------------------------------------------+
| 0001 | 1995 | Chevrolet | Astro | Base     | Clear Lens; Chrome Housing; Pair; 1 pc.; |
| 0001 | 1995 | Chevrolet | Astro | CL       | Clear Lens; Chrome Housing; Pair; 1 pc.; |
| 0001 | 1995 | Chevrolet | Astro | LS       | Clear Lens; Chrome Housing; Pair; 1 pc.; |
| 0001 | 1996 | Chevrolet | Astro | Base     | Clear Lens; Chrome Housing; Pair; 1 pc.; |
| 0001 | 1996 | Chevrolet | Astro | CL       | Clear Lens; Chrome Housing; Pair; 1 pc.; |
| 0001 | 1996 | Chevrolet | Astro | LS       | Clear Lens; Chrome Housing; Pair; 1 pc.; |
| 0001 | 1997 | Chevrolet | Astro | Base     | Clear Lens; Chrome Housing; Pair; 1 pc.; |
| 0001 | 1997 | Chevrolet | Astro | LT       | Clear Lens; Chrome Housing; Pair; 1 pc.; |
| 0001 | 2001 | Chevrolet | Astro | Base     | Clear Lens; Chrome Housing; Pair; 1 pc.; |
+------+------+-----------+-------+----------+------------------------------------------+
```

I'd like to concatenate the years, when the other data matches within the row (SKU, Make, Model, Submodel, Notes). An example of the end result would be this...:

```
+------+-------------+-----------+-------+----------+------------------------------------------+
| SKU  |    Year     |   Make    | Model | Submodel |                  Notes                   |
+------+-------------+-----------+-------+----------+------------------------------------------+
| 0001 | 1995 - 1997 | Chevrolet | Astro | Base     | Clear Lens; Chrome Housing; Pair; 1 pc.; |
| 0001 | 1995 - 1996 | Chevrolet | Astro | CL       | Clear Lens; Chrome Housing; Pair; 1 pc.; |
| 0001 | 1995 - 1996 | Chevrolet | Astro | LS       | Clear Lens; Chrome Housing; Pair; 1 pc.; |
| 0001 | 1997        | Chevrolet | Astro | LT       | Clear Lens; Chrome Housing; Pair; 1 pc.; |
| 0001 | 2001        | Chevrolet | Astro | Base     | Clear Lens; Chrome Housing; Pair; 1 pc.; |
+------+-------------+-----------+-------+----------+------------------------------------------+
```

The query currently looks like...:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
sku,
YearID,
MakeName,
modelname,
SubmodelName,
notes
FROM
TableName
WHERE 1
```

In a similar example to mine, the user was provided with an answer pointing to the usage of "CASE" within the query. The example provided is below, but it is grabbing the minimum, and maximum years on the whole table. The end result is something like this, with only ONE result...

```
+------+-------------+-----------+-------+----------+------------------------------------------+
| SKU  |    Year     |   Make    | Model | Submodel |                  Notes                   |
+------+-------------+-----------+-------+----------+------------------------------------------+
| 0001 | 1950 - 2015 | Chevrolet | Astro | Base     | Clear Lens; Chrome Housing; Pair; 1 pc.; |
+------+-------------+-----------+-------+----------+------------------------------------------+
```

Sample query (with the CASE included)...:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
sku,
CASE
WHEN MIN(YearID) = MAX(YearID) 
    THEN MIN(YearID)
ELSE CONCAT(MIN(YearID), '-', MAX(YearID))
END As Year,
MakeName,
modelname,
SubmodelName,
notes
FROM
TableName
WHERE 1
```

Your help in obtaining my desired result is greatly appreciated. I've been stumped as to how I can do this via SQL.

Comment: My first thought was to do a concatenation of the `MIN` and `MAX` of the year as well, but this will bite you in the ass with something like the Camaro, which was made from 1967 - 2002, then went on hiatus until 2010.  The query would return `'1967 - 2016'`, where you really should have two seperate rows, `'1967 - 2002'` and `'2010-2016'`.  To handle that I think you'd need a cursor to roll through the recordset and inspect for year gaps.  Then I saw this was a mysql and have no idea if it supports cursors or the like, and decided to just leave this comment further explaining the problem.

Comment: Thanks @LDMJoe for your assistance. You point out a concern I've had, and I wasn't sure how I could get it to work, or if it was even possible in this manner. I appreciate that you took the time to provide your insight. :-)

Comment: @LDMJoe I dont see that case in the data

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza True, but that is obviously just a few rows of sample data.  I presume the OP's full data is based on real world data, where this scenario is known to exist.  I just saw a potential stumbling point and made note of it.  The OP can decide if accounting for this is required or not and accept (or not) answers of his own volition accordingly.

Comment: I have change my Answer. please try it again

Comment: @BerndBuffen I appreciate the modification to your answer, but it didn't work on my sample data. It merely returned the data with no concatenation of the years.

Comment: sorry i get it. can you put some sample data on http://sqlfiddle.com/ so that i can test for you. Thanks Bernd

Comment: Hi @BerndBuffen! Of course. I'll be happy to. :-) I'll post a response here as soon as it's up.

Comment: Hi @BerndBuffen! I believe SQLFiddle may be having problems, but I've put the sample data onto there now. [http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ece6ee](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ece6ee) -- Needless to say, I couldn't get anything to execute on there, but perhaps it's an issue on my end.

Comment: Hi @Brian Schroeter , if have change my Answer again. please test it again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Have change it again. please test it and let me know if it works. Sorry for the bad SQL before. i forgot to initialize the variables at the first time.

```
  SELECT
    sku,
    CASE
      WHEN MIN(YEAR) = MAX(YEAR) THEN MIN(YEAR)
      ELSE CONCAT(MIN(YEAR), '-', MAX(YEAR))
     END AS YEAR,
     make, model, submodel, notes
  FROM
    (SELECT @ldfnr:= IF((@old_make = tab.make
      AND @old_model = tab.model
      AND @old_submodel = tab.submodel
      AND @old_notes = tab.notes
      AND (@old_year = tab.`year`
      OR @old_year = tab.`year`-1)) , @ldfnr, @ldfnr+1) AS nr, tab.* ,
      @old_make := tab.make , @old_model := tab.model ,
      @old_submodel := tab.submodel , @old_notes := tab.notes ,
      @old_year := tab.`year`
    FROM TableName AS tab,
      (SELECT @ldfnr:=0, @old_model:='', @old_submodel:='', @old_notes:='', @old_year:='', @old_make:=''  ) AS tmp
    ORDER BY make, model, submodel, notes, `YEAR` ASC) AS mytab
  GROUP BY nr
  ORDER BY nr;

+------+-----------+-----------+-------+----------+------------------------------------------+
| sku  | YEAR      | make      | model | submodel | notes                                    |
+------+-----------+-----------+-------+----------+------------------------------------------+
|    1 | 1995-1997 | Chevrolet | Astro | Base     | Clear Lens; Chrome Housing; Pair; 1 pc.; |
|    1 | 2001      | Chevrolet | Astro | Base     | Clear Lens; Chrome Housing; Pair; 1 pc.; |
|    1 | 1995-1996 | Chevrolet | Astro | CL       | Clear Lens; Chrome Housing; Pair; 1 pc.; |
|    1 | 1995-1996 | Chevrolet | Astro | LS       | Clear Lens; Chrome Housing; Pair; 1 pc.; |
|    1 | 1997      | Chevrolet | Astro | LT       | Clear Lens; Chrome Housing; Pair; 1 pc.; |
+------+-----------+-----------+-------+----------+------------------------------------------+
5 rows in set (0.44 sec)
```

Comment: The Camaro breaks this (see my comment on OP).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Bernd. Unfortunately, the results I received when running this query did not include the sequential concatenation. The results returned just as the original data, with an extra column ("nr"), which started at 1, and increased incrementally by 1.

Comment: sorry, copy paste error. change  **GROUP BY nr;** to **GROUP BY nr ORDER BY nr;** at the end of the Query

Comment: Hi Bernd! Thank you the prompt response. I just tried that as well, to no avail. I'm not getting any errors in the query, but I'm not getting the concatenation to occur either. I really appreciate your help on this.

Comment: Hi @Brian Schroeter , if have change my Answer again. please test it again

Comment: You've done it @BerndBuffen! Thank you so, so much! Answer accepted!

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use the STUFF function with an xml subquery. This will allow you to select information on the same row and concatenate it. I use this for similar queries.

https://sqlwhisper.wordpress.com/2013/03/24/stuff-and-for-xml-path-for-string-concatenation/